# How to auto-refresh/re-run a query every few seconds?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a script running against a database with no GUI. This simple query lets me see its progress:

```
select
    *,
    (select count(*) from domains) as count,
    (select 456976-count(*) from domains) as remaining
from domains
order by domain desc
limit 0, 1;
```

Using MySQL Workbench, how can I automatically refresh/re-run this query every few seconds?

I tried Googling, but didn't come up with anything relevant.

<sup>Aside: the magic number 456,976 is 26^4; it has to do with the script.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a Stored Procedure that calls the query and sleeps every 10 seconds

```
use mydatabase
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `MyDataStatus` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `MyDataStatus` ()
BEGIN
    SET @SecondsToPause = 10;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CurrentCount FROM domains;
    SET @Remaining = 456976 - @CurrentCount;
    WHILE @Remaining > 0 DO
        SELECT *,@CurrentCount as `count`,@CurrentCount as `remaining`
        FROM domains ORDER BY domain DESC LIMIT 0, 1;
        SELECT SLEEP(@SecondsToPause) INTO @SleepValue;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CurrentCount FROM domains;
        SET @Remaining = 456976 - @CurrentCount;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, call the Stored Procedure from DOS Command Line

```
set MYSQL_USER=root
set MYSQL_PASS=password
set MYSQL_MYDB=mydatabase
set MYSQL_CONN=-u%MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PASS% -D%MYSQL_MYDB%
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -ANe"CALL MyDataStatus()"
```

or you could login to mysql

```
mysql %MYSQL_CONN%
```

then call the query at the MySQL prompt

```
mysql> CALL MyDataStatus();
```

## Give it a Try !!!

## Caveat

Please notice I call the COUNT once and subtract it from 456976 to speed up the count a little.

Comment: I ended up re-writing the PHP script that fills the database in C# with a WPF GUI, but since this is the only Windows answer, I've accepted it! Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 7):

You don't state what OS you are using, but under Linux/OSX and other Unix-a-likes you can use the mysql command line tools with the pretty standard `watch` utility to do this. Something like:

```
watch -n 10 'mysql --database=dbname --user=username --password=$(cat /path/to/file/with/mysql/password) --execute="select *, (select count(*) from domains) as count, (select 456976-count(*) from domains) as remaining from domains order by domain desc limit 0, 1;"'
```

Breaking that down:

- `watch -n 10 '<stuff>'` runs `<stuff>` every ten seconds and echos anything that goes to `stdout` to your console window, the single quotes wrapped around the command(s) to run tell your shell not to run any wildcard globbing or other substitutions before giving the command to `watch` (we want this to happen when `watch` runs the command)
- `mysql --database=dbname --user=username --password=password` runs the command line tool against a given DB with the authentication details given
- Using command substitution (`$(cat /path/to/file/with/mysql/password)`) to read the password instead of giving it directly on the command line stops your password being presented to anyone looking at the output of `top` or `ps` (this is why we use the single quotes: without them this substitution will be done before `watch` is in control so the real password will end up on the process list as `watch` runs the resulting command)
- `--execute=<stuff>` tells the command line tool to run `<stuff>` then exit immediately (otherwise it logs in and waits for you to enter commands/queries/statements).
- The rest is just your `SELECT` statement. Each time `watch` runs the `mysql` command it will output the results of this and `watch` will draw them on your screen.

More detail:

- [`mysql` command line syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html)
- [`watch` command man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)
- [`watch` command examples with animated example output](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/05/linux-watch-command-to-monitor-a-command.html)
- [some more examples of simple `mysql` command-line use](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/run-single-mysql-query-command-line/) (the first of many in a simple search, so you will find a lot more examples if you need/want them)

Comment: Good answer David, thanks! Only problem is, I'm running Windows. I've given you an upvote anyway though!

Comment: It would be worth mentioning in your question that you are using Windows, in case others don't spot you comment here and provide more non-windows solutions. The command line tools for mysql are there in Windows, so you might just need to find a `watch` equivalent. Alternately, you could write a simple batch file or power shell script that infinitely loops (until ctrl+c is pressed), sleeping for a bit then clearing the screen then running your query using the `mysql` command line, and run script - not as neat as `watch` but it should achieve the goal in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My requirements were the same but in Git-Bash. As Git-Bash does not have the `watch` command I was able to use the `While` loop as follows:

```
while true; do mysql -u root -p[password] -e "select * from table"; sleep 5; clear; done
```

P.s. There should be no space in -p and [password] i.e. `-p[password]`